# Is a refresh token linked to the web applications client ID / client secret?

Tags: security, oauth, access-token

I have a question regarding security when working with refresh tokens. Lets say I have a web application which has access to a user's google calendar. Therefore I need to do the following steps:

1. Get a client ID and a client secret from Google.
2. The user of my web application gives permission to his calendar.
3. I get a refresh and an access token.
4. I send the access token to the Calendar API and get access to the user's calendar.

I can refresh the access token with the refresh token, which is saved in the database.

What would happen if someone gets access to my database or in general would have the refresh token of one of my users? 
Can an attacker access the calendar with the refresh token or is the token linked to my client ID and client secret? Is it only possible to access the users calendar when my web application authenticates via the OAUTH2 API with my client ID and client secret?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is/should not be possible to use a refresh token with a different client than it was issued to.

Refresh tokens are typically opaque strings, but in the issuer they should be linked to the authenticated client. That is why you need to send your client is and secret along when you use the refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the client is able to keep a `client_id` and `client_secret` from the attacker, the regular approach is to treat and store the `refresh_token` in the same way. So even though technically it is not possible to obtain a new access token without the client credentials, in practice the attacker would get a hold of the client credentials in the same way as he got hold of the refresh token.

Comment: So the only possibility then is to deactivate/change the client ID of your web application?

Comment: if you're able to detect that a refresh token is stolen, you should revoke it; if it is likely that the client_id/client_secret were stolen along with it, the client secret should be rotated; note that the client_id is not a secret and anyone could obtain it